# How to get the value from the list with in the object

Tags: c#-4.0, collections, asp.net-4.0

I am calling a service, service is returning an object that contains a list. In this list number of elements are there like list[0],list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MMKC.jpg),etc...

Now I am trying to get value from the list, but it is not allowing to get the value from the list.
Below is the code which I have written.

```
 //calling a service
        MarkelRate = Markel.MarkelService(username, password, dt, GR.State, classCode, GR.Territory, EachOcc, GeneralAgg, Deductible);
```

[image]

I am trying like this.

[image]

Comment: what are you really trying to do? do you want to get first value of 'list', or what? What is your problem?

Comment: I am trying to get BaseRate from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hemanth Try like this.

```
MarkelRate = Markel.MarkelService(username, password, dt, GR.State, classCode, GR.Territory, EachOcc, GeneralAgg, Deductible);
        foreach (msu.markelcorp.com.Markel.MarkelClassGuide.GLClassRate item in MarkelRate.List)
        {
           string PrmiumRate = item.BaseRate.ToString();
        }
```